# How to make the command connection in silverlight MVVM?

Tags: silverlight

I trying to use MVVM in some silverlight modal that i wrote - 
I wrote the view - and the viewmodel part - but i need to make the command between them and i don't know how to do it.

In the view i have single button that will launch the command.

How to do it ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Look at Commanding: ICommand, ApplicationCommands, ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In View Model

```
private RelayCommand _Command;
public RelayCommand Command
{
  get
  {
    if (_Command == null)
    {
      _Command= new RelayCommand(() =>
      {
      });
    }
    return _Command;
  }
  private set { }
}
```

USE PARAMETERS

```
private RelayCommand<string> _Command;
public RelayCommand<string> Command
{
  get
  {
    if (_Command == null)
    {
      _Command= new RelayCommand<string>((X) =>
      {
      });
    }
    return _Command;
  }
  private set { }
}
```

In View

xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:gs_cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL4"

```
<Button  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="btnSelect" Content="..." Width="25" Height="25" TabIndex="2">
                                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                                <gs_cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=Command,Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    </Button>
```

Comment: What's great about the ICommand setup is you can also pass in ViewModel instances. So RelayCommand<string>((x)... can be replaced with RelayCommand<MyViewModel>((vm)... which gives you direct access to the ViewModel instance in the method being called. This is one way to update other elements of the program when something important happens in a View. See below for example.

Comment: RealyCommand define In Your ViewModel And you can change ViewModel Properties , use this code to send parameter to viewmodel <gs_cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=Command,Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1, Path=SelectedItem}" />

Answer (score 0):

Another version with Parameters, to add to Masoomian's anser:

```
private RelayCommand<MyViewModel> _Command; 
public RelayCommand<MyViewModel> Command 
{ 
  get 
  { 
    if (_Command == null) 
    { 
      _Command= new RelayCommand<MyViewModel>((vm) => 
      { 
        vm.IsBusy = true; // Set a Parameter
        vm.DoSomething(); // Do some work
        // Call other methods on the View Model as needed
        // ...
      }); 
    } 
    return _Command; 
  } 
  private set { } 
}
```